# How to print the equivalent curl command of a c# libcurl invokation

Tags: c#, curl, libcurl, libcurl.net

I'm using libcurl (actually 7.74.0) to send a file via FTPS.
The code is written in C#.

Does exist a way or a libcurl's method to print the equivalent curl command, so I can try the same call on a console?

Real case:
I'm trying to send a file via ftps using a c# program. In most cases I receive FTP 426 error code, but in some cases not.
If i do the "same" request on a console, it ends with success, so I suppose there is something different in the libcurl invoked code between curl and the program

Comment: No, it doesn't exist. But the opposite, curl command to libcurl code exists.